# Assign PHP parameters to a Session if session is empty or parameter is different

Tags: php, session

**Question**

My clients are given a URL with a parameter at the end and when they click on it the URL looks like this

```
www.website.com?utm_content=1223324
```

I want to assign `1223324` into a `session` and carry it across the website till the `utm_content` value is different. If the value is different, I want to carry that new value across the website.

**What Im trying to do**

Im trying to grab the `utm_content` value and carry it across till the user submits my contact form. I am adding `utm_content` to the contact form submission so it comes across to me. If the user clicks on another link with a different value, i want to replace the current `utm_content` id with the new one so the new ID comes across to me through the contact form

**My PHP Code**

```
$getTrackingCodeCurrentURL = $_GET['utm_content'];


if(isset($_SESSION['getSSourceId'])){


    if($getTrackingCodeCurrentURL != $_SESSION['getSSourceId'])
    {
        $_SESSION['getSSourceId'] = $getTrackingCodeCurrentURL;
        echo "Session NOT the same : " . $_SESSION['getSSourceId'];
    }
    else{

        echo "Session SET TO same : " . $_SESSION['getSSourceId'];
    }

 } else {

    $_SESSION['getSSourceId'] = $getTrackingCodeCurrentURL;
    echo "Session not set : " . $_SESSION['getSSourceId'];

}
```

**Issue**

When the visitor goes to another page, the `getSSourceId` doesn't get carried across. I think because it assigns the `$getTrackingCodeCurrentURL` value (which is NULL when the visitor goes to another page) to `$_SESSION['getSSourceId']`. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Put everything inside `if (isset($_GET['utm_content'])) {`

Answer (score 2):

This is all I needed

```
if(isset($_GET['utm_content'])){

    $_SESSION['getSSourceId'] = $_GET["utm_content"]; 
    $getTrackingCodeCurrentURL = $_SESSION['getSSourceId'] ;
    echo "IS SET : ".$getTrackingCodeCurrentURL;

 } else {

     $getTrackingCodeCurrentURL = $_SESSION['getSSourceId'] ;
    echo "NOT SET : ".$getTrackingCodeCurrentURL;

}
```